# Converter BufferedImage para File?

Tags: java, arquivo

Preciso converter uma `BufferedImage` para um `File`. Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não funcionou:

```
File file = null;
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
```

`image` é do tipo `BufferedImage`.

Esse foi o erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: output == null!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)*

Comment: Só para deixar claro: o que você quer é salvar a imagem em um arquivo. `File` é só uma referência ao arquivo, ele não contém dados, então não é realmente possível *converter* dados em um `File`, mas criar uma referência a um arquivo e depois escrever os bytes ou caracteres no arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema foi que você instanciou seu File como `null`.

```
File file  = new File("image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file );
```

Você precisa especificar o caminho da imagem.